# How to put a specific thread to sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

I added names to the threads in my main method. Then, I updated my run method with what Shar1er80 suggested in order to make thread 2 fall asleep ONLY.

Comment: You could supply a boolean to a constructor, to tell the thread to sleep or not.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code showing how you created your thread objects, how you named them, etc...

Comment: You can't put a specific thread to sleep. You can only put the current thread to sleep. The thread itself has to call `Thread.sleep().`

Comment: You can create a signal for triggering the sleeping event. E.g. if (condition){sleep}. And you have to synchronize the condition.

Answer (score 0):

A thread can only pause itself.

That is a thread can't directly pause another thread... **but you can share data between threads** using concurrent data structures such as: Semaphores, Locks, CountDownLatches, ConcurrentHashMaps etc...

With out seeing your exact use case its hard for me to give you specific code. For example I have no idea if you want to resume the thread or just have it pause for specific amount of time and of course its very important what your threads are doing (ie if they are looping or calling blocking IO).

That being said I can't really recommend one of the other posters recommendation of using the thread name. Not only can you not change the name once a thread is started it sometimes is completely out of your control. What I do recommend since sleeping is often about synchronization is having a look specifically at [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and [`Semaphores`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) which have examples in their Java doc.